# Creating library without encapsulation Javascript

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries, encapsulation

I am very new in creation of libraries in javascript and encapsulations in javascript. I created very first library with the help of one or two tutorials from the web.

The example looks like the following,

```
<script>
        var libs=[];
            (function(libs){ 
                function firstLibrary (){ 
                this.initializeHoldings = function () {} 
                  this.myLibrary = function(){ 
                    var _myLibraryObject = [{FirstName: 'Ibrahim', LastName: 'Shaikh', CompanyName: 'Plexitech'}, 
                        {FirstName: 'Nizam', LastName: 'Siddiqui', CompanyName: 'Neoquant'}]; 
                    return _myLibraryObject; 
                  } 
                } 
                libs.customLibrary = firstLibrary;
            })(libs);
            let $ = new libs.customLibrary();
            console.log($.myLibrary());
        </script>
```

This is how my code looks,
now the confusions are,

1): What are the difference between libraries and encapsulations in
 javascript?

2): How can I create library without encapsulating it in javascript?

3): Does encapsulation always create library?

Yes, I know it might be a silly question for some of you but many newbies might get confused on this.

Comment: [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) - "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." :-) (Context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wujVMIYzYXg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1): What are the difference between libraries and encapsulations in javascript?

A "library" is a set of functions/classes. "Encapsulation" doesn't really have a meaning as a unit of code like "library." Wikipedia's [short definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) of "encapsulation" are pretty good:

> - A language mechanism for restricting direct access to some of the object's components.
> - A language construct that facilitates the bundling of data with the methods (or other functions) operating on that data.

As you can see, neither means anything like "library." But you would probably *use* encapsulation in parts of your library.

> 2): How can I create library without encapsulating it in javascript?

Probably, if you didn't have any data maintained by the library that you needed to prevent other code from using, and didn't need to combine data with methods.

> 3): Does encapsulation always create library?

No, not at all. They're largely unrelated terms and concepts.